# Transformar classe com métodos estaticos em interface

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Tenho uma *custom class* chamada `ArrayList`, que criei para manusear objetos em um pequeno projeto meu, mas gostaria de abstrai-la ainda mais, transformando em interface. Desta forma, eu poderia criar outras classes que fazem a mesma coisa com bancos diferentes(nessa classe, salva em um `txt`, mas eu tenho outra que faz as mesmas coisas em um arquivo JSON e futuramente vou fazer uma pra salvar em MySQL).

Como posso efetuar essa transformação, caso ela seja viável?

Segue a classe `ArrayList`

```
class ArrayList {

    private static $list = null;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    private static function getList() {
        if (!isset(self::$list)) {
            $linha = "";
            if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/model/DB.txt')) {
                $banco = dirname(__DIR__) . '/model/DB.txt';
                $a = fopen($banco, 'r');
                $linha = fread($a, filesize($banco));
                self::$list = unserialize($linha);
            } else {
                self::$list = Array();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function add($item) {
        self::getList();
        self::$list[] = $item;
    }

    public static function remove($item) {
        self::getList();
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::size(); $i++) {
            if (self::get($i) === $item) {
                unset(self::$list[$i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        self::$list = array_values(self::$list);
    }

    public static function get($indice) {
        self::getList();
        return self::$list[$indice];
    }

    public static function size() {
        self::getList();
        return sizeof(self::$list);
    }

    private static function gravar() {
        $texto = serialize(self::$list);
        $a = fopen(dirname(__DIR__) . '/model/DB.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($a, $texto);
        fclose($a);
    }

    public static function atualizarDB() {
        self::gravar();
    }

}
```

O que eu estou tentando fazer seria algo assim:

```
interface ArrayList{
getList();
add($item);
save();
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o problema, para fazer isso basta criar a interface e definir todos os métodos(assinaturas) sem implementação e depois cada classe que implementa-la, precisará criar o código que varia entre as classes.

Comment: é mais prático criar uma classe abstrata, visto que tem algumas funções que são iguais independente da implementação, como `add`, `get`, `remove` e `size`

Comment: @rray o problema é que, manuseando json ou txt, se eu alterar o arquivos a partir de locais diferentes, a instancia que está implementando a interface não irá atualizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira coisa que teria que fazer é deixar de usar elementos estáticos nesta classe. Não faz sentido usar uma interface em uma classe essencialmente estática.

Eu acho estranho ter um método de atualização de banco de dados dentro de uma estrutura de dados genérica assim. Eu acho que isto deveria estar fora, mas fica a seu critério.

Também não sei os requisitos e exatamente o objetivo da criação da interface, mas acredito que o que deseja é isto:

```
interface iArrayList {
    public function add($item);
    public function remove($item);
    public function get($indice);
    public function size();
}
```

Se quiser pode colocar outros métodos obrigatórios e que sejam gerais.

Aí essa classe, além das mudanças sugeridas seria escrita assim:

```
class ArrayListDB implements iArrayList
```

A próxima provavelmente seria:

```
class ArrayListJson implements iArrayList
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Interface.php).

Comment: É exatamente isso que quero fazer, mas usando metodos estaticos, se meu arquivo for alterado, eu tenho em tempo real a alteração quando chamar `getList()`, se eu instanciar um objeto exemplo `ArrayListJson`, isso não acontece.

Comment: Interfaces e métodos estáticos não se juntam. A segunda parte do comentário não faz sentido pra mim, provavelmente você sabe mais do eu sobre o que está acontecendo na sua classe. De qualquer forma este é outro problema não relacionado com a pergunta.

Comment: Se duas pessoas usarem a aplicação ao mesmo tempo e enquando a primeira fizer uma alteração no json ou no txt adicionando outro objeto, a segunda chamar o `getList` por exemplo, a alteração do primeiro usuário não será refletida para o segundo, usando metodos estaticos, elas são refletidas imediatamente(pelo menos nos testes que fiz). Usando classe instanciada, eu não sei como efetuar esse controle de alterações.

Comment: Me parece que toda a arquitetura disto está errada. A solução não é nesta. Tem vários problemas nisto, "funciona no teste que eu fiz" não significa que está certo. Mas o problema está se afastando do que foi perguntado. Mesmo que a solução seja fazer a classe ser estática, e não é, não teria como usar `interface`. É só isto que posso te responder dentro do escopo da pergunta. Se tem outro problema, faça outra pergunta mostrando ele.

Comment: É eu sei, é um projeto convertido do java:/. Talvez usando `Singleton` e tornando a instancia de arraylist unica no servidor daria um resultado semelhante, não?

Comment: Como eu disse o problema parece ser outro ao que foi perguntado, mas a única coisa que você vai conseguir convertendo em Singleton é colocar a interface nele, não resolve a arquitetura errada. Só vai misturar mais responsabilidades na mesma classe.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Eu simplesmente diria que existe um problema de lógica, e nesse momento, aplicar padrões às cegas não ajuda em nada. Especifica melhor qual tipo de aplicação é.

Comment: @Edilson é uma atividade da faculdade aqui, realmente está com problemas de modelagem. Como não vou fazer tudo do zero, depois de ler a resposta do bigown, decidi por separar responsabilidades e criando DAO's separados para cada tipo de salvamento(txt, json ou outros). Dá trabalho mas pelo menos fica mais organizado.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Imagina, 2 usuários com acesso simultâneo à mesma instância de um objecto não é o mesmo que fazer um login simultâneo em máquinas diferentes ? E assim sendo, eles praticamente possuem as mesmas propriedades, logo as acções de um são das do outro. É açgo assim.

Comment: @Edilson bagunçou minha mente toda esse problema kk. Vou fazer outra pergunta, mais didatica porque não entendi bem um lance de POO.